# How to delete everything in a table sql

Tags: android, sqlite

Im trying to figure out how to delete the whole table on the click of a button so lets say i had a button called Delete i want to press it and delete everything in the table. 

 I tried this but it didnt work i didnt kno wwhat to put in the button

```
void deleteAll()
{
    SQLiteDatabase db= ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, null, null);
}
```

Code:

```
package f.s.l;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class HotOrNot {
public static final String KEY_ROWID ="_id";
public static final String KEY_NAME ="persons_name";
public static final String KEY_HOTNESS ="persons_hotness";

private static final String DATABASE_NAME ="HotOrNotdb";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE ="peopleTable";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION =1;

private DbHelper ourHelper;
private final Context ourContext;
private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;

private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

public DbHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" +
        KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
        KEY_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
        KEY_HOTNESS + " TEXT NOT NULL);"
    );
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
    onCreate(db);
}
}

public HotOrNot(Context c){
    ourContext =c;
}

public HotOrNot open() throws SQLException {
    ourHelper = new DbHelper(ourContext);
    ourDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public void close(){
    ourHelper.close();
}

public long createEntry(String name, String hotness) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(KEY_NAME, name);
    cv.put(KEY_HOTNESS, hotness);
    return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
}

public String getData() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String [] columns = new String[]{ KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_HOTNESS};
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    String result = "";

    int iRow = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
    int iName = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME);
    int iHotness = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_HOTNESS);

    for(c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {
        result = result + c.getString(iRow) + " "+ c.getString(iName) + " " + c.getString(iHotness) + "\n";
}

return result;
}

}
```

Comment: Please post your logcat errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just do

```
db.execSQL("DELETE * FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE);
```

This will not remove the table but will delete all the rows in the table.

Comment: `DELETE FROM tablename;` should be correct. There is no `*` in [DELETE](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_delete.html)

Answer (score 0):

try using the drop table command , i think it must be drop table